# TypeScript factory pattern says property doesnt exist

Tags: javascript, inheritance, typescript, abstract-class, factory-pattern

Im trying to implement the factory pattern in TypeScript, but i can't access the child-functions that doesnt exist in the super class. (It works, but the compiler is giving me an error).

Structure:

```
abstract class Animal {
    walk(meters:number) { ... }
}

class Elephant extends Animal {
    walk(meters:number) { ... }
}

class Eagle extends Animal {
    walk(meters:number) { ... }
    fly(meters:number) { ... }
}
```

My factory:

```
class Zoo {
    animals:Animal[] = [];

    addAnimal(type:string): Animal {
        var a: Animal;

        switch(type) {
            case 'elephant':
                a = new Elephant();
                break;
            case 'eagle':
                a = new Eagle();
                break;
            default:
                throw new Error('Animal of type \'' + type + '\' doesn\t exist');
        }

        this.animals.push(a);
        return a;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var sammy:Animal = addAnimal('eagle');
sammy.fly(15);
```

This gives me: 
Error: TS2339: Property 'fly' does not exist on type 'Animal'.

Also i tried to cast:

```
var sammy:Eagle = addAnimal('eagle');
sammy.fly(15)
```

Which gives me:
Error: TS2322: Type 'Animal' is not assignable to type 'Eagle'.
 Property 'fly' is missing in type 'Animal'.

I made a code playground on TypeScript page: http://bit.ly/21yXXjf

Comment: You're enforcing a return type in your `addAnimal` function. Remove that and your error will go away

Comment: Did you change `addAnimal(type:string):Animal` to simply `addAnimal(type:string)`?

Comment: Thats still not working. :( Type 'Animal' is not assignable to type 'Eagle'. Property 'fly' is missing in type 'Animal'.

Comment: Yes. You can also try out in the playground i added to the question: http://bit.ly/21yXXjf

Comment: Make sure your internal `a` isn't assigned a type as well. Here's a working playground solution: http://goo.gl/lzLtjU

Comment: Thanks mate, its working now! But shouldnt the above code be working in Java? (In Java we couldnt have a variable without a type, and return without return type)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Java, so I wouldn't know about implementing this there, but TypeScript will default to an `any` type if nothing is specified. If you want to assign specific types to everything I would personally suggest a different approach, but that's just me

Comment: What kind of approach would you suggest? Im just thinking that TypeScript is not right here, when this code would work within Java or C++.

Comment: It's actually a good question. I'm not sure about the internals of TypeScript, but remember it is an attempt at creating a static typing paradigm for JavaScript, which is dynamically typed. It's pretty reasonable to assume it's not as tight as languages that have types baked in from the start. Still, a good question I don't really know the answer to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Quick Fix

You can use type assertions to take the type checking away from TypeScript and into your own hands.

```
var sammy = <Eagle><any>zoo.addAnimal('eagle');
sammy.fly(15)
```

This can result in problems, so there is a better solution to your problem (and the factory problem in general)...

## Better Solution

Use specialized signatures to return the correct type based on the static string:

```
class Zoo {
    animals:Animal[] = [];

    addAnimal(type: 'elephant'): Elephant;
    addAnimal(type: 'eagle'): Eagle;
    addAnimal(type: string): Animal;
    addAnimal(type: string): Animal {
        var a: Animal;

        switch(type) {
            case 'elephant':
                a = new Elephant();
                break;
            case 'eagle':
                a = new Eagle();
                break;
            default:
                throw new Error('Animal of type \'' + type + '\' doesn\t exist');
        }

        this.animals.push(a);
        return a;
    }
}

var zoo = new Zoo();

// No type assertion needed, sammy is an eagle!
var sammy = zoo.addAnimal('eagle');
sammy.fly(15)
```

Comment: Wow thats super nice! Here is the final playground example: http://bit.ly/1UqcJtC

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an animal with type Animal and then trying to access  property 'fly', which does not exists in this type, possible solution is to add property 'fly' to Animal class, or remove Animal type from addAnimal method  `addAnimal(type:string): Animal {}`, or you could change your code to this: 
 
`var sammy = <Eagle>myZoo.addAnimal('eagle'); // This woudl work without errors!`  
 
Just add `<Eagle>` type to your method call